# electron load website external website as content

Tags: reactjs, electron

Good Morning,

is it possible to load only a website as content in electron and run it in electron? or do I have to redesign my bundler für my react JS app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package that do exactly what you need

https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier

Just install with:

npm install nativefier -g

And after:

nativefier "http://medium.com"

Comment: Thanks I gonna try this later.

Comment: Does this work for websites hosted on AWS Cloudfront as well? I tried it but it stucks on 80% ...

Comment: It should be possible to open dev tools with `Ctrl+Shift+I`

Comment: retried it todays morning ... worked fine ... sorry! 

Do I have to bundle the app again each time I change the natified website or does it load each time the website again?

Comment: I think it's just a browser opening url with online contents.

Comment: that would be amazing. Thanks

Comment: I bundled it for mac as well It runs on the mac where I bundled it but not on others ... any idea?